# SASS: Check if @content is specified in mixin

Tags: sass

Is it possible to check if @content was specified in SASS?

I want to create a mixin that makes sure @content is always provided, so I can throw an error when it is not. From what I investigated, this does not seem to be possible, but are there any workarounds?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181469/sass-mixins-default-value-for-content